# Java regular expression with hyphen

Tags: java, regex

I need to match and parse data in a file that looks like:

```
4801-1-21-652-1-282098
4801-1-21-652-2-282098
4801-1-21-652-3-282098
4801-1-21-652-4-282098
4801-1-21-652-5-282098
```

but the pattern I wrote below does not seem to work.  Can someone help me understand why?

```
final String patternStr = "(\\d+)-(\\d+)-(\\d+)-(\\d+)-(\\d+)-(\\d+)";
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile(patternStr);

while ((this.currentLine = this.reader.readLine()) != null) {
    final Matcher m = p.matcher(this.currentLine);
    if (m.matches()) {
        System.out.println("SUCCESS");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks correct.
Something odd is conatined in your lines, probably. Look for some extra spaces and line breaks.

Try this:

```
final Matcher m = p.matcher(this.currentLine.trim());
```

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried escaping the `-` as `\\-`?

Comment: Aha, the evil invisible whitespace strikes again :-)

Answer (score 3):

It should work. Make sure there is no invisible characters, you an trim each line. You can refine the code as :

```
final String patternStr = "(\\d{4})-(\\d{1})-(\\d{2})-(\\d{3})-(\\d{1})-(\\d{6})";
```

Answer (score 1):

There is white space in the data

```
 4801-1-21-652-1-282098
 4801-1-21-652-2-282098
 4801-1-21-652-3-282098
 4801-1-21-652-4-282098
 4801-1-21-652-5-282098

final String patternStr = "\\s*(\\d+)-(\\d+)-(\\d+)-(\\d+)-(\\d+)-(\\d+)";
```